# Wordpress Access allowed to fewer pages till user logs in

Tags: php, functions

Is it possible in wordpress,by editing theme functions.php, to stop user access for all pages except Home, about-us, contact-us until a user is logged in to the system?
All buddypress and wordpress page and posts redirects user to a login page?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Members plugin to restrict access to certain pages, very handy.

In the menu section you can check if user is logged in, and show extra menu items if logged in by adding code similar to this in your template

```
                if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-in-menu' ) ); /* logged in menu is a separate menu */
                    global $current_user;
                    get_currentuserinfo();
                    ?>
                    <div id="userinfo">
                      <p>Logged in as:</p>
                      <p>
                      <?php echo ($current_user->user_firstname.' '.$current_user->user_lastname); ?>
                      </p>
                      <div  class="b_logout"><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(home_url()); ?>">Log out</a></div>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                } else { ?>
                    <div id="b_login">
                      <ul><li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li></ul>
                    </div>
                <?php } /* end if user logged in */ ?>
```